# MongoDB $set item in array which does not exists with object as element results in object instead of array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Updating elements inside an array is explained here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays

But in the docs seems the case missing where the array does not exists yet in the document. Example:

If have this document:

```
{
  _id: 'some-id',
  otherprops: 'value'
}
```

And I want it to become like this:

```
{
  // ...
  settings: {
    friends: [
      {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 28
      }
    ]
  }
  // ...
}
```

In this situation I dont know if there is already a settings.friends array. So my query looks like this:

```
{
  $set: {
    'settings.friends.0.name': 'John Doe',
    'settings.friends.0.age': 28
  }
}
```

However the document results in like this:

```
{
  // ...
  settings: {
    friends: {
      0: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 28
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way to force mongodb to create an array instead of an object in my example **but with using dot notations only.**

Comment: Looks like there is no way to tell MongoDB what resulting data type must be. By default MongoDB converts dot notation path to object. You can not cast path to specific type and there is no explicit syntax to tell MongoDB that the provided path must result in array :(

Answer (score 0):

> try this.

```
{
    $addToSet: {
        "settings.friends": [
            {
                name: 'John Doe',
                age: 28
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case I would not do it with dot notation - but I want to. The reason is: If I dont do it with dot notation I have to check the existing document if an array exists. Imagine you want to perform an update on a document only on one property. If I would do this what you have shown the other property will get lost (if I not merge it with the existing document, what I dont want to do)

Comment: The above updated code will satisfy your requirement

Comment: I just saw that your example is also not what I was locking for. In your example it will always add a new item to the array - but what if the object on arrays position 0 already exists and I only want to do an update of the properties name and age instead of adding them? So the problem is still the same: How to solve to force mongodb using arrays while doing dot notation?

Comment: you can use $set instead of $addToset

Comment: ... then I have the problem I have described in my question. When I do $set 'settings.firends.0.name' then instead of an array mongodb will save an object.

Comment: Hey @TJR, did you find a solution for your problem? Because I have the exact same one...

Answer (score -1):

This is working in mongodb version v4.0.9. I have tested your usecase in my machine.

```
db.collection.update(
  {
    "_id": 'your_key'
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "settings.friends.0.name": "ABCD"
    }
  },
  {
    "upsert": "true"
  }
)
```

Before Update my collection entry was

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "col1" : "val01",
    "settings" : {
        "friends" : [
            {
                "name" : "Ramraj",
                "age" : 28
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

After update my collection entry was

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "col1" : "val01",
    "settings" : {
        "friends" : [
            {
                "name" : "ABCD",
                "age" : 28
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly my case. My case is that "settings.friends" does not exist. In your case it exists.